# Place value in an input field i.e., in a textbox in an html form from a servlet

Tags: java, html, servlets

What I'm trying to do here is to redirect to an html page with a form from servlet and as I redirect, is it possible to set values in a textfield of that form? Like the way I get the values from the form using request.getAttribute(), similarly is there a way to set values in a input element in an html form from a servlet?
Would greatly appreciate your help, thank you.

Comment: can you explain why you want to do this?

Comment: You can use jsp page instead of html. Then you can create dynamic pages easily.

Comment: The requirement is to make this using html only but I'm not sure if it cannot be in html, that's why i got here, and as of why I'm doing this, I'm creating a web page form where user can register from a registration form and submit the details. And if the user wants to edit, then the user is redirected to the same registration page with his old details in the textboxes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java does not provide method to set parameters in servlet.
If you *must* do this using HTML here are two options:

**(I still recommend using JSP)**

1.display the registration page using `PrintWriter#println()` in servlet.

```
response.setContentType("text/html");  
out.println("blah blah blah");
out.println("<input name='username' type='text' value='"+javaVariable+"'");
out.println("blah blah blah");
```

2.In your HTML page make an AJAX call to servlet that returns data you need and populate form elements with this data.

Comment: Great, I'm not familiar with AJAX, but at least I got to know that there's a solution for it, will surely learn it, thanks a lot! :)